# An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.ts

Tags: reactjs

I have an onSummarySubmit that submits a form with some data, I get the response of that submission and use it to call another query (getPayoutDetail).

```
  const [payoutDetails, setPayoutDetails] = useState<PayoutDetailData>();
  const [getPayoutDetail] = useLazyFetchPayoutQuery();

  console.log(payoutDetails, 'test');

  const onSummarySubmit = async () => {
    const response = await publishDraft().unwrap();
    console.log(response); // this returns
    if (!response || !response.data) {
      console.error('publishDraft did not return expected response');
      return;
    }
    try {
      const { data: payoutDetail } = await getPayoutDetail(
        response.data.inpay_unique_reference
      );
      setPayoutDetails(payoutDetail.data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    onFinish();

    return response;
  };
```

The issue is that the response (console.log(response)) in the onSummarySubmit returns some data as follow:

```
{
    "data": {
        "debtor_account": {
            "id": "45701229351",
            "scheme_name": "VirtualAccount"
        },
        "end_to_end_id": "34624352",
        "inpay_unique_reference": "49N8T8A",
        "amount": "453254435.0",
        "currency": "CAD",
        "timestamp": "2023-05-10T08:40:36.000Z",
        "state": "received"
    }
}
```

But the console.log(payoutDetails, 'test'); always returns undefined and I am not sure why. Also in this part of the onSummarySubmit, in the if statement:

```
 if (!response || !response.data) {
      console.error('publishDraft did not return expected response');
      return;
    }
```

in relation to `!response` it complains that *An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthiness.ts(1345)* while for `!response.data` it says that Property 'data' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

any clues ?

Comment: What is the return type of `await publishDraft().unwrap()`?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you problem originates from your line -

`const { data: payoutsData } = useFetchPayoutsQuery(inpayReference);`

I don't know what `useFetchPayoutsQuery` does, but the initial value you implicitly gave `inpayReference` is undefined, because by not giving `useState` a value - it sets the value as `undefined`.

try giving it a better suited initial value, in regards to whatever `useFetchPayoutsQuery` does.